# can't go to Recovery Mode

Tags: adb, fastboot

i have a oppo neo 7 (android 5.1) that doesn't want to go to recovery mode. when i tried to go to recovery mode, it just goes back to normal restart. So i tried using adb, so i used fast boot mode, but it failed it says : wiping userdata...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 838860800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7328
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 3200
    Label: 
    Blocks: 204800
    Block groups: 7
    Reserved block group size: 55
Created filesystem with 11/51296 inodes and 6651/204800 blocks
target reported max download size of 134217728 bytes
wiping cache...
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 167772160
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 5120
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 40960
    Block groups: 2
    Reserved block group size: 15
Created filesystem with 11/10240 inodes and 1705/40960 blocks
erasing 'userdata'...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.002s

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to get to the recovery mode would be to press and hold all the buttons on your device. That would take it into recovery mode.
Using adb you can get to the recovery mode by the below command.

adb reboot recovery